# Internal shell command in gmake file causes 'HERE' document shell script to exit

Tags: shell, makefile, ibm-midrange

Given this simple gmake makefile, titled makefile.weird:

```
symlinks : 
    @ln -s realfile.txt linkfile.txt
```

And this shell script:

```
ksh -s << EOF
date
gmake -f makefile.weird symlinks
date
echo "This should print some stuff"
EOF
```

Only the first 'date' command is printed.  The ln command is run by gmake, but the shell script simply ends after gmake is called, effectively ignoring the "here" document portion of the script.  I've never seen this before.  Anyone have an explanation and possible workaround?  I could just remove the command from the makefile, but my curiosity has me held down tight on this one.  It shouldn't matter, but this occurs on an AS/400 running ksh93 via their PASE system (a way to run AIX stuff on IBMi).

Answer (score 2):

`gmake` is inheriting its standard input from `ksh`, whose standard input is the here document, so `gmake` (or something called by `gmake`) is consuming the rest of the input intended for `ksh`.

The shell script should probably just be something like

```
#!/bin/ksh
date
gmake -f makefile.weird symlinks
date
echo "This should print some stuff"
```

which avoids the problem of standard input being shared by everything.

Answer (score 0):

Through hacking the script (there's a reason I needed it to work via 'here' document), I came up with two possible solutions:

Throw the gmake into the background and call "wait" on it

```
ksh -s << EOF
date
gmake -f makefile.weird symlinks &
wait
date
echo "This should print some stuff"
EOF
```

Add "< /dev/null" to the end of the gmake command.  This works if your gmake doesn't need stdin input.

```
ksh -s << EOF
date
gmake -f makefile.weird symlinks < /dev/null
date
echo "This should print some stuff"
EOF
```